# Using .ppk file to ssh from a Mac

Tags: ssh, certificate, ssh-keys

I have a .ppk file that I need to use to ssh into a server. I am using OS X Yosemite.

I converted it to .pem file using this: `puttygen keyfile.ppk -O private-openssh -o keyfile.pem`

However, when I try to add that to OS X's keychain, it says unable to retrieve info from the file. I changed permissions on it with `chmod 600 keyfile.pem` but still no luck.

So I just tried through the terminal:

```
ssh -i keyfile.pem root@ip_address
```

However, this just times out. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you can see more details with ssh -i keyfile.pem root@ip_address -vvv

Comment: show your output with -vvv

Comment: Bty if it's giving time out error then it might be your server issue also ! are you able to ping our server ?

Answer (score 0):

First, check your connection with your server by ping command
If you can ping your server, try to do this

- copy your .pem file to ~/.ssh/
- adding this command to the bottom of your config file

> IdentityFile "~/.ssh/keyfile.pem"

- connect to your server:

> ssh root@ip_address